# Output buffer sorted using Metal Compute Kernel?

Tags: ios, sorting, gpu, metal

I have a compute kernel that calculates the brightness value of each point supplied in an input buffer of 2D points:

```
struct DrawingPoint {
    half x;
    half y;
};

kernel void sortPoints(device DrawingPoint *artPoints [[buffer(0)]],
                             device DrawingPoint *artPointsOut [[buffer(1)]],
                             device atomic_int &counter [[buffer(2)]],
                             texture2d<half> colorTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                             uint id [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {

    constexpr sampler default_sampler;

    DrawingPoint artPoint = artPoints[id];

    float2 colorTextureCoord = float2(artPoint.x, artPoint.y);
    half4 color = colorTexture.sample(default_sampler, colorTextureCoord);
    half gray = (color.r * 0.21h) +  (color.g * 0.72h) + (color.b * 0.07h);

    int counterValue = atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);

    artPointsOut[counterValue] = artPoints[id];
}
```

The above code just outputs the input point to the output buffer in the same order.

What I would like to do is output the points in order of brightness (from lowest to highest or vice-versa).

Is that possible with Metal? Are there any sorting functions or libraries? I can find a number of sorting libraries for OpenGL, but not for Metal.

Comment: This question is a bit broad as-stated. I’m not aware of any general purpose sorting routines in the Metal standard library or MetalPerformanceShaders framework, but you could probably adapt an existing bitonic sort routine from another shading language.

Comment: I agree, but thought there might be some magic I wasn't able to find. Thanks for your suggestion - I found a bitonic Metal project: https://github.com/TG908/MetalSort - but seems that the output is only roughly ordered (not sure if that's how it is supposed to work). Since fast sorting is such a widespread topic, I would think that a Metal Sort tutorial wold have far reaching appeal. Hint hint!